# How to know when all images from document did load in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image, load

I'm realoading a `<div>` content with an ajax function with Ruby On Rails i'm realoading a `partial` into a `div` and i want to know hot to know when all images have loaded because now i have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").load(function(){
        alert("ok?");
    });
});
```

but with this i keep getting an alet for every image on this partial....

i don't know iuf there's a selector like `$(allimgs)` or something like that, what do i have to do to catch when all images are loaded?

Many Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with this code, are you loading it through Ajax? And what is the problem, does it fire too often?

Comment: attach on complete/load on the last child of the img

Comment: Yeas I'm loading this through Ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to ensure that all images loaded without errors you have to roll your own. If not you can use .load like already shown which will fire when the browser is done loading assets.

To roll your own, do something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var imgs = $("img"), cnt = imgs.length;

    imgs
    .load(function(){
      if(!--cnt) {
        /* all images loaded */
      }
    })
    .error(function() { /* whoops an image failed to load */});
  });
```

Comment: This one looks the more similar to my final code but every other answers are working code !

Answer (score 2):

Will do something like:
First we count how many imgs we have in our page, every img load will decrement count by 1, and when it is 0, means that all images are loaded.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var allimgs = $("img");
     var count = allimgs.length;

     allimgs.load(function(){
          if(--count == 0) {
              alert("all images are loaded");
          }
     })
  });
```

---

**EDITED**

If the browser is caching the images, try this instead:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var allimgs = $("img");
     var count = allimgs.length;

      $("img").one('load', function() {
           count--;
           if(count == 0) {
              alert("all images are loaded");
           }
      }).each(function() {
           if(this.complete) $(this).load();
      });
  });
```

Comment: This one is working but i'm having problem with cached images, they are not triggering the event

Comment: Grrat Answer man i gave you my vote but the other answer seems more like my final code but this one works just right as well as the other answer

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use the image loaded plugin, to ensure that your code deals with cached images etc. https://github.com/paulirish/jquery.imgloaded

and then your code

```
var total_number_of_images  = $("img").length;
var loaded_images = 0;

$("img").load(function(){
               loaded_images++;
if loaded_images =   total_number_of_images {
// do something ...

}              });
```

Comment: I Tried to edit your code, it's missing parentheses on the conditional and another equal symbol to the comparison, but i don't have editing privileges now