# Wait until popup window finishes loading the execute javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a popup window which displays multiple images, the amount of images can change depending on what the user does. These images take about 1.5 seconds each to load but that can change depending on the machines speed.

I need a way to wait for the popup to finish loading all the images and then execute a script, what's the best way of doing this?

**Edit:**

```
popup.document.body.setAttribute("onload","alert('hello');");

//Wait for the popup to finish loading
popup.onload = function() {
    popup.alert("loaded");
};
```

None of the above are working...

**Edit 2**
Now works thanks to Diodeus. Here is the code:

```
popup.document.write(
            '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">'+
            '<html><head>'+
            '<script type="text/javascript">'+
            'var i = '+doc('print_container2').getElementsByTagName('img').length+'; var c = 0;'+
            'function count_loaded() {'+
                'if (c == i) {'+
                    'document.getElementById("print_container").style.display = "block";document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";'+
                    'focus();print();close();'+
                '}'+
            '}'+
            '</script>'+
            '  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">'+
            '</head><body><h1 id="loading">Loading... please wait...</h1>'+
            '</body></html>'
        );
```

Here are the images:

```
$hires .= "<img onLoad=\"c++;count_loaded();\" id=\"L".$key."_".$key2."_".$i."\" data-quantity=\"".$value2['quantity']."\" onclick=\"disable_print(this,'print_container')\" src=\"".$_SESSION['ROOT_DIR']."php/generateimage.php?imgname=".$_SESSION['ROOT_PATH']."data/images/".$value2['location']."&restraint=".$restraint."\" class=\"\" />";
```

See the onLoad event.

Comment: If I am not mistaken `window.onload` event will fire only after all images are loaded

Comment: I'm trying that but nothing seems to work, see updated post

Comment: `body.onload` aren't the same as `window.onload`. only the later fires `after` everything is loaded

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know when all images from document did load in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182240/how-to-know-when-all-images-from-document-did-load-in-javascript)

Comment: That's using jQuery @Diodeus and i'm not using that.

Comment: The principle is the same. You need to put an onload handler on the images and count them as they load. None of the document, window or body methods do what you want.

Comment: Put that as an answer @Diodeus